# "BufferedInputStream" vs "FileInputStream with configured size"

Tags: java, file-io, stream, iostream, bufferedinputstream

Case 1 => BufferedInputStream is created and I would like to read() 12 bytes at a time, but it buffers upto 1024 bytes (say for instance) for performance improvement. So, it reads 1024 bytes in a single sys call USING the passed FileInputStream provided in BufferedInputStream constructor.

Case 2 => In FileInputStream.read(byte[]), I can pass a byte array of size 1024. Which means in each sys call, my FileInputStream reads 1024 bytes.

From Case 1 and Case 2, I cannot see any betterment BufferedInputStream provides in terms of run time performance. All it does is that wraps FileInputStream around and does the same what I did in Case 2.

can anyone help me understand better?

Comment: Note that case #2 doesn't guarantee that 1024 bytes are read. It could be fewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can effectively re-implement what `BufferedInputStream` does by reading fixed blocks from the underlying `InputStream`, but it's not quite as easy:

- first, a `read(byte[])` call is not guaranteed to fill the array, you have to check the return value. A `BufferedInputStream` handles this for you.
- If you manually manage your buffer then having some data structures cross multiple buffere instances can be a pain to implement, `BufferedInputStream` provides the well-known `InputStream` interface without your code having to care about the buffereing.
- Due to that last point `BufferedInputStream` can be passed to anything that accepts an `InputStream`.

In the end `BufferedInputStream` is just pure Java code, so you *can* do anything it does manually as well, but there are very few reasons to do so.

**tl;dr** `BufferedInputStream` is just a simple way to gain some performance by reducing system calls and buffering reads while still providing the normal `InputStream` interface. You *could* implement everything it provides without it, but there is almost never a reason to.

Comment: As we speak of performance, there is a difference between `read()` and `read(buff[]` exposed by streams... Comparing one implementation with another should aim analogous methods.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to say, @dbl.

Comment: OP says: `read() 12 bytes at a time, but it buffers upto 1024 bytes` In such usage scenario `BufferedInputStream::read` will return 1byte per read operation, not 1k...

Comment: I'm not convinced that he actually meant the no-argument `read` method up there or if he just didn't specify the `byte[]` argument type ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after you learn about decorator design pattern, you can understand better about BufferedInputstream.

BufferedInputStream not just buffer your data, more important is that it implements the InputStream interface. You can treat it like anyother InputStream and combine it with other InputStream to create a more powerful InputStream.

You can implement your own BufferedInputStream as you want, but I think it's not as easy as you think.